# Javascript Random Name Always Returning Same item

Tags: javascript, html, random

I have this javascript code that collects the name from an array of string and return a random name, But everytime I fire the function, it is returning the same name; I need to refresh the web page to generate a new random name.

```js
var items = ["Tony","Peter","Chris","Thor","Roger","Steve"];
var  randomItem = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];

function getRandom(){
  document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = randomItem;
}
```

```html
<button id="getRandom" onclick="getRandom()">Get Random name</button>
<span id="random">Click button to generate new name</span>
```

Comment: That is because you never change `randomItem`.

Comment: When and how often is `var randomItem = ...` being executed…?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the random function inside your `getRandom()` function

```js
var items = ["Tony","Peter","Chris","Thor","Roger","Steve"];


function getRandom(){
  var  randomItem = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
  document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = randomItem;
}
```

```html
<button id="getRandom" onclick="getRandom()">Get Random name</button>
<span id="random">Click button to generate new name</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You create only once and never change `randomItem` - that is why you're getting always the same item. Simplyfy your code as follows:

```js
var items = ["Tony","Peter","Chris","Thor","Roger","Steve"];

function getRandom(){
  document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
}
```

```html
<button id="getRandom" onclick="getRandom()">Get Random name</button>
<span id="random">Click button to generate new name</span>
```